# How can I change the font size when I was editing a cell in a table

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was developing a spreadsheet editor. When I was editing a specific cell in the table, how can I change the cell's font size?
I used `getElementById`
Code here:

```
<title>Gold Sheets</title>
<div id="toolbar">
    <select name='Font Size' id="ft_size" onchange="changeSize(this);">
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="14">14</option>
        <option value="16" selected>16</option>
        <option value="18">18</option>
        <option value="24">24</option>
    </select>
</div>
<script>
function changeSize(e) {
    document.getElementById('textarea').style.fontSize = e.value + 'px'
}
</script>
<br>
<br>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td contenteditable id='textarea'></td>
            <td contenteditable id='textarea'></td>
            <td contenteditable id='textarea'></td>
        </tr>
   </table>
```

Comment: Hi, did you want `px` or `pt`? Your currently using `px`.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer Cleared Because of changing the question**

Comment: But I want to enlarge the text, not the dropdown

Comment: There is no text in the code you  use as sample.
For that you need to set the element you want to update using query selector method:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: I added the contenteditable div element into the question

Comment: Righ, there you go a sample using your div.